# Scraping 'next' page after finishing in the main one using Rules

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make a spider that scrapes products from a page and, when finished, scrape the next page on the catalog and the next one after that, etc.

I got all the products from a page (I'm scraping amazon) with

```
rules = {

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//a[contains(@class, "a-link-normal") and contains(@class,"a-text-normal")]') ), 
                                callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)

    }
```

And that works just fine. The problem is that I should go to the 'next' page and keep scraping.

What I tried to do is a rule like this

```
rules = {

        #Next Button
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('(//li[@class="a-normal"]/a/@href)[2]') )),

}
```

Problem is that the xPath returns (for example, from this page: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mac+makeup&lo=grid&page=2&crid=2JQQNTWC87ZPV&qid=1559841911&sprefix=MAC+mak%2Caps%2C312&ref=sr_pg_2)

```
/s?k=mac+makeup&lo=grid&page=3&crid=2JQQNTWC87ZPV&qid=1559841947&sprefix=MAC+mak%2Caps%2C312&ref=sr_pg_3
```

Which would be the URL for the next page but without the www.amazon.com.

I think that my code is not working because I'm missing the www.amazon.com before the url above.

Any idea how to make this work? Maybe the way I went in doing this is not the right one.

Comment: The URLs being relative should not be the issue. Since this is Amazon, I encourage you to write a regular spider (instead of a CrawlSpider subclass) to be able to debug your spider more easily and be able to handle complex scenarios you might encounter.

Answer (score 2):

Try using urljoin.

```py
link = "/s?k=mac+makeup&lo=grid&page=3&crid=2JQQNTWC87ZPV&qid=1559841947&sprefix=MAC+mak%2Caps%2C312&ref=sr_pg_3"


new_link = response.urljoin(link)
```

The following spider is a possible solution, the main ideas is use the parse_links function to get the links to the individual page which yields the response to the parse function, and you can also yield the next page response to the same function untill you've crawled through all the pages.

```py
class AmazonSpider(scrapy.spider):

    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mac+makeup&lo=grid&crid=2JQQNTWC87ZPV&qid=1559870748&sprefix=MAC+mak%2Caps%2C312&ref=sr_pg_1'
    wrapper_xpath = '//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div' # Product wrapper
    link_xpath = './//div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/a/@href' # Link xpath
    np_xpath = '(//li[@class="a-normal"]/a/@href)[2]' # Next page xpath


    def parse_links(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath(self.wrapper_xpath):
            link = li.xpath(self.link_xpath).extract_first()
            link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse)

        next_page = response.xpath(self.np_xpath).extract_first()

        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse_links)
        else:
            print("next_page is none")
```

Comment: Thanks!, but where should i put the joined link so the spider keeps scraping after the page is finished? The only function im using right now is the parse_item I have that scrapes the data from a product

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, I'll try this out